# How do I calculate the exponential regression with the following?

Tags: exponential-function, graphing-functions, regression

Not sure where to ask but I have a task to calculate the exponential function for curve fitting.

So I have this exponential function: `v(x)=a-(b*exp(-d*x))`

I wanted to find the a, b and d with the following points (x and y):

`[0.33, 0.09964675364309147]
[0.66, 0.10389448386358434]
[0.99, 0.10724269474326696]
[1.32, 0.1081921873807889]
[1.6500001, 0.10984130617227435]
[1.98, 0.11308957045853361]
[2.3100002, 0.11663767452506293]
[2.64, 0.11928625925078204]
[2.97, 0.12188487067978944]
[3.3000002, 0.1245334554055085]
[3.63, 0.1268822003509575]
[3.96, 0.1292309452964065]
[4.29, 0.13142977035172046]
[4.6200004, 0.13372854200045778]
[4.9500003, 0.13537766079194324]
[5.28, 0.13752651255054554]
[5.61, 0.13952544441901277]
[5.94, 0.14157434958419166]
[6.2700005, 0.14422293430991076]`

gnu plot results:

`a = 0.23596
b = 0.138802
d = 0.072086`

This was easily calculated via gnuplot, if you do not know what it is, it is a program that generate plots, calculate fit, and more. But in my case I wanted to manually calculate it, at least for the a, b and d.

Comment: [Here is a MathJax Tutorial !](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin. Are you sure of your data example ? Did you plot the points on a graph? They are not consistent with the kind of function expected.

Comment: @JJacquelin as I said it is just a sample plot. They might not be right but you can expect the right plot at your end. Do not know what is the put on as a possible plot. As i am not sure how to calculate the result.

Comment: What gnuplot gives for $a,b,d$ with your data ?

Comment: @JJacquelin Added real datapoint that I generated from gnuplot, see above for edits

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin. Meanwhile I posed an answer. I will check with your data later (Not enough available time just now).

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin. My answer is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are several methods of regression which gives approximates of the parameters of the supposed convenient function. Each method has specific advantage and drawback. You have to understand that it is not serious to propose a particular method without information about the context. That is why a representative example of data (not a no significative one) is a useful information to give a pertinent answer and an example of numerical calculus helping to apply without mistake the proposed method with other data.

The fonction that you chose to be fitted is non-linear. Generally the usual methods of regression involve an iterative process and require initial guess of the parameters (by the user or by various kind numerical approaches).

A special direct method (i.e. not iterative, no initial guess required) exists. But I am reluctant to propose it without estimating the advantages and drawbacks in a specific context.

Nevertheless, this regression method is summarized below. Without more information about your case of application, one cannot say if this method will be accurate enough for you.

[image]

This comes from : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

LATTER ADDITION.

With the data provided in the OP question :

[image]
NOTE : Probably there is something wrong in the use of gnuplot or in the transcription of the results from gnuplot because the fitting should be better than the blue curve. Please, check the gnuplot calculus and the copy of the numerical results.

NOTE : With the very simple method proposed above, the fitting appears satisfactory (red curve). If you need more accuracy according to some specific criteria of mean error (absolute or relative or other criteria) one need a non-linear fitting method. I suppose that gnuplot could be able to do that. If not, try more efficient regression packages.

DETAILS OF COMPUTATION :

[image]

Comment: This is a very detailed answer, Thank you. Also, just to let you know that I am not really a math wiz, just programming this to the app. Some of the value or symbols for calculating them is I am unknown with.

Comment: Of course, in order to program the above method, one need to know at least the use of the symbol of sum $\Sigma$ and a bit of matrix calculus.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin. Even if you know nothing about matrix calculus, it is possible to apply the method and carry out the numerical calculus. Where are you stuck ?

Comment: Well I am stuck within the bounds of: from k=1 to k=n

Comment: $$S_2=0+\frac12(y_2+y_1)(x_2-x_1)$$ $$S_3=S_2+\frac12(y_3+y_2)(x_3-x_2)$$ $$S_4=S_3+\frac12(y_4+y_3)(x_4-x_3)$$ etc. up to $$S_n=S_{n-1}+\frac12(y_n+y_{n-1})(x_n-x_{n-1})$$ Compute the $S_k$ one after the other and check with the values written on the table in my answer.

Comment: About the sums, for example $\Sigma(x_k-x_1)^2$ means : $$(x_1-x_1)^2+(x_2-x_1)^2+(x_3-x_1)^2+...+(x_n-x_1)^2$$ You should obtain $=229.760114$

Comment: Other example :   $\Sigma(x_k-x_1)S_k$ means : $$(x_1-x_1)S_1+(x_2-x_1)S_2+(x_3-x_1)S_3+...+(x_n-x_1)S_n$$ You should obtain $=27.214579$